# Laravel 7 Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to do a **Custom Authentication with third-party authentication API** which means I have a login endpoint in another project (Lumen Project). and I've found a tutorial about how to do it but using `Laravel 5.2` on [here](https://www.minddevelopmentanddesign.com/blog/add-custom-api-authentication-to-laravel/).

I'm using:

- Laravel 7
- PhpRedis/Redis

**The ERROR:**

> RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.

The tutorial is kinda simple. The steps follow as:

1. Install PhpRedis and Guzzle.
2. Create custom auth controllers which include `Throttles.php` where works the **Cache**.
3. Override Laravel’s authentication middleware (`Authenticate.php`).

I've done all the steps and I didn't miss anything. What I've tried to fix this but none of them works:

1. I used the `web` middleware in the login routes but It won't work and I don't know why

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
       Route::get('login', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@showLoginForm');
       Route::post('login', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@login');
       Route::get('logout', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@logout');
   });
   ```

And you can see here my `Kernel.php` by default.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

2. Configure the Cache driver

My `.env` file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

My `database.php`

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'read_write_timeout' => 60,
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

        'session' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 1,
        ],

    ],
```

And my `session.php`

```
'connection' => 'session',
```

I've tried all that and none of these worked. I don't know what's happening, maybe Laravel 7 needs something else or I'm missing something. Just someone could know why the `web` middleware isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flor,

I was facing the exact same problem. Got it working by making the following change in
AuthenticationRequest.php

class AuthenticationRequest extends Request

to

class AuthenticationRequest extends FormRequest

You would need the following import as well

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

Comment: I guess in newer versions of laravel, when we create a new request with the following command php artisan make:request someSampleRequest, it uses the FormRequest dependency.